# How to programmatically mirror a video file in Android with no third-party dependencies

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm new to image and video manipulation on Android and have a scenario where I'd like to load a video file (.mp4) into my app and programmtically modify it such that each frame in the video is horizontally flipped (mirrored). The video should be unchanged otherwise. One constraint is that I cannot use any third-party frameworks, so this needs to be done using the Android SDK only, if possible.

Is this possible, and if so, how should I do this? I came across the `MediaCodec` class, but I haven't found any solid examples illustrating how to use this class.

Answer (score 0):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java There is file  **TextureRender.java** you need change matrix U-V and you can flip, rotate.

```
      private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
    // X,    Y,   Z,  U,   V
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
    };
```

It works like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ptS.png) (just ignore small texture).
Just experiment with U-V coordinates.